# Easy way to fill colum with sequential dates in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I want to fill column A with sequential dates. Like this:

```
01/12/2015
02/12/2015
03/12/2015
```

This is easy for a small number of rows. Is there an easy way to do this for six months worth without having to edit each date individually?

I could use another excel sheet with `=CONCATENATE(ROW(), "/12/2015")` but there are pitfalls of missing leading zeroes.

Comment: Do you want **dd/mm/yyyy** or **mm/dd/yyyy** ??

Comment: In the form of  dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
01/12/2015
=A1+1
```

You then click on the little extra square on the bottom right of A2 and drag down until you have the required number of days.

Answer (score 0):

If you want **dd/mm/yyyy**, pick a cell and enter:

```
=DATE(2015,12,ROWS($1:1))
```

apply the proper format and then copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a function Fill/Series for that.

1. Make sure your field is formatted as Date (whichever date format you prefer)
2. Use Fill/Series (in 2010 and 2013, it's on the Home ribbon, on the very right)
3. enter a step (1?) and a unit (day?), and an end date; hit return, done.

Alternatively, you can select all cells you want it to go in, and skip the entering of the end date, it will fill the selected area.

Note that you can chose 7 days or 2 months or whatever you like for steps, not just 1 day.